# Amazon Elastic Transcoder Http Request Error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I need to use Amazon Elastic Transcoder for an mvc project.
I wanted to use it via http request as described by documentation.
While creating header of request I need to create Authorization parameter as described which I think I did. 
But the response returns this error;
**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.**

Host parameter of request is = **elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443**

URl for post is = **https://elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/2012-09-25/jobs**

Authorization parameter is something like  = **AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=accesskey/formatteddate/us-east-1/elastictranscoder/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target,Signature=xxxxx**

Anyone have an idea of the reason for this error?

Comment: Check leading and trailing spaces in your signature string, then in others. Strongly recommend to use Fiddler, and double check see the request headers there, to see what is really going in the wire

Comment: What is weird is the expected Canonical String and  String-to-Sign is same as returned by response.

Comment: I suppose it's just a replica of what you've sent, so I would not think this has any diagnostic value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated AWSSDK from nuget for mvc project and there was an api for elastic transcoder;
here is the simple way to do:

`var response = etsClient.CreateJob(new CreateJobRequest()
            {
                PipelineId = "pipelineid", //pipeline.Id,
                Input = new JobInput()
                {
                    AspectRatio = "auto",
                    Container = "auto",
                    FrameRate = "auto",
                    Interlaced = "auto",
                    Resolution = "auto",
                    Key = "folder1/video.flv"
                },
                Output = new CreateJobOutput()
                {
                    ThumbnailPattern = "",
                    Rotate = "0",
                    PresetId = "1351620000001-000040",
                    Key = "output.mp4"
                }
            });`